# coding challenge solution with a hidden bug

Tags: ruby, algorithm, oop, data-structures

Recently I took a coding challenge on turing. The question was :

You will be given a string list(ops) as input.

- If its an integer you have to keep a record of it
- If it's a character 'C', you have to remove the last recorded element
- If it's a character 'D', you have to double the last element and record it
- If it's a character '+', you have to add the last two elements and record it
  Return the final sum of records.

Example input,
`ops = ["5", "2", "C", "D", "+"]`
`output = 30`

I was able to write the code, however it did not pass. In retrospective, I am just trying to find what went wrong. Please find my code below:

```ruby
def score_calculator
    scores = []
    ops.each do |rec|
        scores << rec.to_i if rec.is_a?(Integer)
        scores << scores.last(2).sum if rec == '+'
        scores << (scores.last.to_i * 2) if rec = 'D'
        scores.pop if rec == 'C'
    end
    return scores.sum
end
```

Comment: It seems you're doing a wrong comparison in `rec = 'D'`, it's an assignment.

Comment: Another issue is, your first check `rec.is_a?(Integer)` is not going to go through as input given a list of chars.

Comment: Please add your test-cases so we can maybe point out cases also to test.

Comment: Thanks @tadman good suggestion pointed out

Comment: @MrSmith42 above shown input `["5", "2", "C", "D", "+"]` was the only test case I had.

Comment: @coder2023: If I implement an algorithm I start to come up with my own test-cases. Of case the one example input-output-pair is also a test-case. But cases like only one character, multiple times the same character, an empty array are the cases I would come up first as tests.

Comment: You said, "You will be given a string list(ops) as input." That's incorrect. You are given an array of (presumably) strings. Also, you should say "If its *the string representation of* an integer you have to keep a record of it". That's not just me being picky. Initially I was thinking the array might include integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby this is often done with a `case` instead of trailing `if`. This means inadvertent assignment is impossible if done correctly. `case rec` and `when 'D'` will always be safe.

For example:

```
scores <<
  case rec
  when /\A\-?\d+\z/
    rec.to_i
  when '+'
    scores.last(2).sum
  when 'D'
    (scores.last.to_i * 2)
  when 'C'
    scores.pop
  else
    # ...?
  end
```

Comment: This code is running into below error since Integer comparison with a character is skipped in the first check
`+': nil can't be coerced into Integer (TypeError)`

Comment: It coul dbe you have something that doesn't match any of these branches, so you should catch that in the `else`, maybe `raise "Unknown input element #{rec.inspect}"`. In your `if` chain code it just ignores values, potentially obscuring errors. Another fix here is `scores.compact.sum`.

Comment: Note that the `Integer` test only works on actual integers, as in of that class, where `5` is an `Integer` and `"5"` is a `String`. Your data looks like integer *strings*, as in you should `when /\A\d+\z/` to match those. The Ruby `case` statement uses `===` internally, which means it can do a *lot* of things pretty effortlessly.

Comment: Perfect, I just needed that. I'll try it out

Comment: While the integer issue got fixed, another issue seen is `scores.pop` returns the popped value & pushes to the scores array. There is a need to add `next` right after `scores.pop`

Comment: Good catch, yeah, that's certainly a good solution.

Comment: tadman, negative integers? coder2023, while there may be details to be worked out the main point is that this problem is well-suited to the use of a case statement. Among other things notice how nicely it reads. One other thing: you selected an answer a mere 34 minutes after you posted the question. Such quick selections may discourage some members from posting other answers and increases the likelihood that any errors in the selected solution will be missed. There's no rush. Next time consider waiting substantially longer before making a selection.

Comment: Yes now i have chosen the right answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could still run your code with a little improvement..

```
def score_calculator
    scores = []
    ops.each do |rec|
        scores << rec.to_i if rec.match?(/\A\-?\d+\z/)
        scores << scores.last(2).sum if rec == '+'
        scores << (scores.last.to_i * 2) if rec == 'D'
        scores.pop if rec == 'C'
    end
    return scores.sum
end
```

Comment: Thanks this is working, however is there a way that we could still run a switch case code here instead of custom comparisons?